# Fragment Rotation not restoring current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragmentactivity that starts on Fragment A then can be change to Fragment B. If i am on Fragment B and i rotate my device. It loads the original Fragment A not Fragment B. I am Loading both Fragment A and B pragmatically. I thought android was supposed to save which Fragment i was on automatically i am not overriding  onSaveInstanceState

This is how i am loading the fragments

```
FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.fragholder, new MainFragment());
    t.commit();
```

Comment: Post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to your manifest and android takes care of everything for you

Comment: Per the officail doc on the Activity class on the configChanges attribute:"Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change". Reference to noted doc:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate your device, it destroys your Activity and recreates its. So assuming Fragment A is the default Fragment, then it is logical that it would load that when the Activity is recreated. So you would need to override onSaveInstanceState to store which Fragment is visible and then reload that Fragment in onCreate.

Reference to relevant Activity Lifecycle doc:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Okay is there a away to store a reference to the actually fragment? From what i can see i can only save primitive data types. Would setRetainInstance(true) help me in this case. Although i am not completely sure how to use this method

Comment: What I would do is just define constants or an enum that corresponds to a Fragment, and then just store those.

Comment: So to answer, no you couldn't store the Fragment itself, just a primitive type that maps to a fragment.

Comment: In all honesty, I have never even heard of setRetainInstance, so I am unaware of its precise workings :/